# jQuery setTimeOut: in for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, for-loop, settimeout

I'm having a little trouble with the setTimeOut-function. Although I saw other topics concerning this feature, I still don't get it.

I want to spawn 5 "orcs", but not at the same time. So I wanted to give each a delay of fe 5 seconds. The best thing I created was an infinite loop, but I don't know why it didn't stop after 4.

```
for (var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
    (function (z) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#gameBoard").append("<img class='Orc' src='Img/Orc.gif' alt='Orc'/>");
            $( ".Orc" ).animate({ "left": "+=100%" }, 20000 );
            console.log("test");
        }, 4000);
    }(z))
}
```

This will only spawn one Orc. Why's this happening?

*It doesn't have to be with a passed variable.*

Any ideas?

Comment: the code you've posted _should_ stop, but it'll create all four orcs simultaneously (albeit four seconds after the loop finished).  Also, since you're not using `z` asynchronously there's no need for the closure over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the delay to be different *for each* orc, you must pass the `setTimeout` a different delay per orc:

```
for (var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
    (function (z) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#gameBoard").append("<img class='Orc' src='Img/Orc.gif' alt='Orc'/>");
            $( ".Orc" ).animate({ "left": "+=100%" }, 20000 );
            console.log("test");
        }, 4000 * z);
    }(z))
}
```

Notice that I am multiplying the delay by `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this:

```
var orcsSent = 0;

function sendOrc() {
    $("#gameBoard").append("<img class='Orc' src='Img/Orc.gif' alt='Orc'/>");
    $( ".Orc" ).animate({ "left": "+=100%" }, 20000 );
    console.log("test");

    if(orcsSent < 5) {
        orcsSent++;
        setTimeout(function () {
             sendOrc();
        }, 4000);
    }
}

sendOrc();
```

Comment: NB: no need for the anonymous function around `sendOrc()` - just call `setTimeout(sendOrc, 4000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use if and then call the function again.

for example

```
var step = 0
function SpawnOrcs(){
    [code for orc spawn]
    if (step <4)
    {
        step++
        setTimeout(SpawnOrcs,[time to wait in ms])
    }
}
```

Comment: never _ever_ pass a string argument to `setTimeout()`

Comment: because that's how we wrote JS in the '90s.  It works, but it's nasty, prone to security problems, and prevents things like scoping from working propelry.

Comment: Okay, I changed it. What security problems could it lead too?

Comment: all of the same ones that `eval` has, AFAIK.

Comment: Also, convention says don't TitleCase your functions unless they're supposed to be called as a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For a cleaner implementation of @lpg's answer:

```
function sendOrcs(n) {
    (function loop() {
        if (--n < 0) return;
        $("#gameBoard").append("<img class='Orc' src='Img/Orc.gif' alt='Orc'/>");
        $( ".Orc" ).animate({ "left": "+=100%" }, 20000 );
        setTimeout(loop, 4000);
    })();
}
```

NB: this will spawn the first Orc immediately, not after 4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! This might become handy if I advance further in my game.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are Orc names!

Try this:

```
function spawnOrcs(numberOfOrcs) {

    var interval = 2000;
    var orcNames = ["Graklak Glasha", "Ougigoth Batul", "Zoughat Ushug", "Graman Lash", "Grushnag Sharn", "Urgan Bumph", "Raghat Durgat", "Xujarek Uloth", "Wumkbanok Bor", "Gnarlug Umog"];

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOrcs; i++) {
        var name = orcNames[i % orcNames.length];
        (function(i, name) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("Spawned Orc:", name);
            }, interval * (i + 1))
        })(i, name);
    }

}

spawnOrcs(5);
```

I'll wait patiently over here while you think about marking this as the best answer ever! :D

Comment: Lol ;) I might implement that in the future! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Your Orcs only have names, but no bodies.

Comment: If the name does its job right, the fear it causes means no body is needed!